# Keep submenu open after its been clicked

Tags: html, css, submenu

Is it possible to keep a submenu open, even after it has been clicked?

For example, when you click Information, a sub menu appears as well as loading a new page. But is it possible to keep the sub menu open, even after the new page has loaded? I want the sub menu information to be available at all times, but only appear when clicked.

Here is the html -

```
<div id="nav">

<nav>
<ul id="menu" style="list-style-type: none;">

    <li id="sub">
    <a href="#">information</a>
        <ul>
            <li> Hello, and welcome to this site</li>


        </ul>
    </li>
```

And here is the css -

```
#nav {
text-align:center;
list-style: none;

}
ul#menu {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 332px;
}
ul#menu:after {
content: "";
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-top: 20px;

}
ul#menu li {
float: left;
list-style:none;
}
ul#menu li a {
color: #666666;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 35px;
text-decoration: none;

}
ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #ccc;
}
a.selected-page, ul#menu a.selected-page:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
li#sub ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index: 22222;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
}
li#sub ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
border-top-style: none;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: left;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;

}
ul#menu li#sub:hover ul {
display: block;
}
ul#menu li#sub ul li:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to add a class when your on that page which keeps the submenu open. Something like "active".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an iframe below your nav bar (obviously you need to adjust the width, height and..), and change the src of iframe on clicking the menu item, this will satisfy your need.

Comment: or a better solution would be to load the pages with ajax in a div.